# Unit testing ControllerAs with forms in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, unit-testing, controlleras

I have the following situation with Angular:

`Controller`

```
function Controller () {
    // form used in template
    this.form ...
}
```

Template that has a form and uses this controller

`Template`

```
<div ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
    <form name="ctrl.form">
    ...
</div>
```

I have to say I'm in general confused why Angular doesn't have a better way of adding the form to the controller other than automatically adding either `this.form` or `$scope.form`, depending on how you use controllers, but that's I guess another question.

The real issue I have right now is that I'm not sure how I should test this. If I just instantiate the controller in the test, then my form is undefined

`$controller('Controller as ctrl')`

I did find a way, by just compiling the template

```
$scope = $rootScope.$new();
$compile(template)($scope);
```

But because `ng-controller` in the template starts a new scope, I can't access the controller directly with `$scope.ctrl`, instead I'd have to do something like `$scope.$$childHead.login`

... and I feel it's getting too complicated. edit: not to mention that $$ indicates a 'private' property.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it myself, but I'm leaving it here unaccepted because I don't think the solution is very nice. If anyone knows a better way, please post.

The problem with compiling templates is that it's also not possible to insert mock services in the controller, at least I didn't figure it out. You get a controller instance on $scope, like `$scope.ctrl`, but that's it.

The second attempt was to locate just the form in the template, compile and add it to a controller that was instantiated separately. This worked, but not really, because the $scope for the form and controller were different and so any update to a field didn't reflect on the controller state.

The way it works in the end is to instantiate the controller with a $scope

```
ctrl = $controller('Controller as ctrl', {
        someDependency: mockDependency,
        $scope: $scope
    });
```

and then to compile the partial template (just the form) with the same $scope

```
var formTpl = angular.element(template).find('form');
form = $compile(formTpl)($scope);
```

This way, the controller ends up in `$scope.ctrl`, but because the form is already named `name="ctrl.form"` it gets inserted into `$scope.ctrl.form` and it's visible inside a controller.

Answer (score 0):

When using `controllerAs`, you can access your form in tests like so:

```
// 1. Create a new scope
var $scope = $rootScope.$new();

// 2. Run the controller
var Controller = $controller("Controller as ctrl", { $scope: $scope });

// 3. Compile the template against our scope
// This will add property $scope.ctrl.form (assuming that form has name="ctrl.form")
$compile(angular.element(templateHtml))($scope);

// 4. Controller.form should now also be defined
expect(Controller.form).toBeDefined();
```

Meanwhile mocking can be achieved by using angular's [$provide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide):

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module(function ($provide) {
    function ApiServiceMock() {
        this.getName() = function () {
            return "Fake Name";
        };
    }

    // Provide our mocked service instead of 'ApiService' 
    // when our controller's code requests to inject it
    $provide.value("ApiService", ApiServiceMock);
}));
```

Full example (using both - mocking & form compilation with controllerAs):

Main app code:

```
angular.module("my.module", [])

    .service("ApiService", function () {
        this.getName = function () {
            return "Real Name";
        };
    })

    .controller("Controller", function (ApiService) {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.someProperty = ApiService.getName();
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
    <form name="ctrl.form">
        <input type="email" name="email" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Test:

```
describe("Controller", function () {
    var $scope,
        Controller;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("my.module"));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module(function ($provide) {
        function ApiServiceMock() {
            this.getName() = function () {
                return "Fake Name";
            };
        }

        $provide.value("ApiService", ApiServiceMock);
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $compile) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        Controller = $controller("Controller as ctrl", { $scope: $scope });

        // FIXME: Use your own method of retrieving template's HTML instead 'getTemplateContents' placeholder
        var html = getTemplateContents("./my.template.html"),
            formTpl = angular.element(html).find('form');

        $compile(formTpl)($scope);
    }));

    it('should contain someProperty', function () {
        expect(Controller.someProperty).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('form should contain an email field', function () {
        expect(Controller.form.email).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```